# LWC Fullcalendar select event not working properly

Tags: lightning-web-components, fullcalendar

I pulled source from: https://github.com/markslott/lwc-fullcalendar and it works nicely though I had to make small change at line 132 of the main.js

```
//return matchesMethod.call(el, selector);
return el.matches(selector);
```

The issue I am having is that I want to automatically create events for all days that occur in a selection of days.  The dateClick works for a single day, but the select event throws an error that says this.calendar is undefined.  I don't understand what is missing since the logic is virtually identical between the dateClick and select events other than the select is using a loop...

**js code**

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
import { LightningElement, api, track} from "lwc";
import { ShowToastEvent } from "lightning/platformShowToastEvent";
import fullCalendar from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/fullCalendar";
import { loadStyle, loadScript } from "lightning/platformResourceLoader";
import getEventsNearbyDynamic from "@salesforce/apex/FullCalendarController.getEventsNearbyDynamic";
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

//global variables
var objectName;
var startField;
var endField;
var colorField;
var additionalFilter;
var allDayField;
var titleField;

export default class FullCalendarComponent extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    calendar;
    fullCalendarInitialized = false;

    @api titleField;
    @api objectName;
    @api startField;
    @api endField;
    @api colorField;
    @api additionalFilter;
    @api aspectRatio;
    @api allDayField;
    @api height;

    @api weekView;
    @api dayView;
    @api listView;

    @track calendarLabel;


    connectedCallback() {
        this.addEventListener('fceventclick', this.handleEventClick.bind(this));
        //this.addEventListener('mousewheel', this.handleScroll.bind(this));  
    }

    renderedCallback() {
        if (this.fullCalendarInitialized) {
            return;
        }
        this.fullCalendarInitialized = true;

        //set global vars
        objectName = this.objectName;
        startField = this.startField;
        endField = this.endField;
        colorField = this.colorField;
        additionalFilter = this.additionalFilter;
        allDayField = this.allDayField;
        titleField = this.titleField;

        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, fullCalendar + "/packages/core/main.js"),
            loadStyle(this, fullCalendar + "/packages/core/main.css")
        ])
        .then(() => {
            //got to load core first, then plugins
            Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, fullCalendar + "/packages/daygrid/main.js"),
            loadStyle(this, fullCalendar + "/packages/daygrid/main.css"),
            loadScript(this, fullCalendar + "/packages/list/main.js"),
            loadStyle(this, fullCalendar + "/packages/list/main.css"),
            loadScript(this, fullCalendar + "/packages/timegrid/main.js"),
            loadStyle(this, fullCalendar + "/packages/timegrid/main.css"),
            loadScript(this, fullCalendar + "/packages/interaction/main.js"),
            loadScript(this, fullCalendar + "/packages/moment/main.js"),
            loadScript(this, fullCalendar + "/packages/moment-timezone/main.js"),
        ]).then(() => {
            console.log("init");
            this.init();
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
          console.log("error", error);
          this.dispatchEvent(
          new ShowToastEvent({
              title: "Error loading FullCalendar",
              //message: error.message,
              variant: "error"
          })
        );
      });
  }

  init() {
      var calendarEl = this.template.querySelector(".calendar");
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
      this.calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      plugins: ["dayGrid", "timeGrid", "list","interaction","moment"],
      views: {
          listDay: { buttonText: "list day" },
          listWeek: { buttonText: "list week" },
          listMonth: { buttonText: "list month" },
          timeGridWeek: { buttonText: "week time" },
          timeGridDay: { buttonText: "day time" },
          dayGridMonth: { buttonText: "month" },
          dayGridWeek: { buttonText: "week" },
          dayGridDay: { buttonText: "day" }
       },
  
       eventClick: info => {
           const selectedEvent = new CustomEvent('fceventclick', { detail: info });
           console.log("eventClick",info);
           this.dispatchEvent(selectedEvent);

           info.event.remove();
       },

       eventMouseEnter: info => {console.log("mouse enter", info)},

       select: function(info) {
           console.log('selected ' + info.startStr + ' to ' + info.endStr);
           let startDate = new Date(info.startStr + 'T00:00:00');
           let endDate = new Date(info.endStr + 'T00:00:00');

    
           for (let d = startDate; d < endDate; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
               this.calendar.addEvent({
                    title: 'dynamic event',
                    start: new Date(d),
                    allDay: true
               });
           }
    
       },

       dateClick:info => {
           console.log("date click", info);

           var date = new Date(info.dateStr + 'T00:00:00'); // will be in local time

           this.calendar.addEvent({
               title: 'dynamic event',
               start: date,
               allDay: true
           });
       },

       selectable: true,
       selectMinDistance: 200,
       header: false,
       /* header: {
           left: "title",
           center: "today prev,next",
           right:
      "listDay,listWeek,listMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,dayGridMonth,dayGridWeek,dayGridDay"
      }, */
      eventSources: [
          {
                events: this.eventSourceHandler,
                id: "custom"
          },
          //{
          //  events: "https://fullcalendar.io/demo-events.json",
          //  id: "demo"
          //}
      ],
    });
    this.calendar.render();
    this.calendarLabel = this.calendar.view.title;
  }

  nextHandler() {
     this.calendar.next();
     this.calendarLabel = this.calendar.view.title;
  }

  previousHandler() {
      this.calendar.prev();
      this.calendarLabel = this.calendar.view.title;
  }

  dailyViewHandler() {
      this.calendar.changeView(this.dayView);
      this.calendarLabel = this.calendar.view.title;
  }

  weeklyViewHandler() {
      this.calendar.changeView(this.weekView);
      this.calendarLabel = this.calendar.view.title;
  }

  monthlyViewHandler() {
      this.calendar.changeView('dayGridMonth');
      this.calendarLabel = this.calendar.view.title;
  }

  listViewHandler() {
      this.calendar.changeView(this.listView);
      this.calendarLabel = this.calendar.view.title;
  }

  today() {
      this.calendar.today();
      this.calendarLabel = this.calendar.view.title;
  }

  refresh() {
      var eventSource = this.calendar.getEventSourceById('custom');
      eventSource.refetch();
  }

  handleScroll(event) {
      console.log("handleScroll");
      event.stopImmediatePropogation();
  }


  handleEventClick(event) {
      let info = event.detail;
      console.log('Event: ' + info.event.title);
      console.log('Coordinates: ' + info.jsEvent.pageX + ',' + info.jsEvent.pageY);
      console.log('View: ' + info.view.type);
      console.log(info);
      this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
          type: 'standard__recordPage',
          attributes: {
              recordId: info.event.id,
              actionName: 'view',
          },
      });
      // change the border color just for fun
      //info.el.style.borderColor = 'red';

  }

  eventSourceHandler(info, successCallback, failureCallback) {
      getEventsNearbyDynamic({
          startDate: info.start,
          endDate: info.end,
          objectName: objectName,
          titleField: titleField,
          startField: startField,
          endField: endField,
          colorField: colorField,
          allDayField: allDayField,
          additionalFilter: additionalFilter
      })
      .then(result => {
          if (result) {
              let events = result;
              let e = [];
              for (let event in events) {
                  if (event) {
                      e.push({
                          title: events[event][titleField],
                          start: events[event][startField],
                          end: events[event][endField],
                          Id: events[event].Id,
                          id: events[event].Id,
                          color: events[event][colorField],
                          allDay: events[event][allDayField]
                   });
               }
           }
           console.log("num events = ",e.length);
           successCallback(e);
       }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error("error calling apex controller:",error);
    failureCallback(error);
  });
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap"
        style="background:#ffffff; padding-bottom:0.5rem;padding-left:0.5rem;padding-right:0.5rem;padding-top:0.5rem;overflow-y:auto">
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_8-of-12 slds-col_bump-right">
            <h2 class="slds-text-heading_medium">{calendarLabel}</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_3-of-12">
             <div class="slds-clearfix">
                <div class="slds-float_right">
                    <div class="slds-button-group" role="group">
                        <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon" onclick={previousHandler}>
                            <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:chevronleft" alternative-text="Previous" size="small">
                            </lightning-icon>
                        </button>
                        <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon" onclick={nextHandler}>
                            <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:chevronright" alternative-text="Next" size="small">
                            </lightning-icon>
                        </button>
                        <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon" onclick={refresh}>
                            <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:refresh" alternative-text="Next" size="small">
                            </lightning-icon>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_3-of-12">
            <div class="slds-button-group" role="group">
                <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon" onclick={today} style="margin-right:1em">
                    <lightning-icon icon-name="standard:today" alternative-text="Today" size="small">
                    </lightning-icon>
                </button>
                <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon" onclick={listViewHandler}>
                    <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:list" alternative-text="List View" size="small">
                    </lightning-icon>
                </button>
                <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon" onclick={dailyViewHandler}>
                    <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:dayview" alternative-text="Day view" size="small">
                    </lightning-icon>
                </button>
                <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon" onclick={weeklyViewHandler}>
                    <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:weeklyview" alternative-text="Weekly View" size="small">
                    </lightning-icon>
                </button>
                <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon" onclick={monthlyViewHandler}>
                    <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:monthlyview" alternative-text="Monthly View" size="small">
                    </lightning-icon>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="background:#ffffff;" class="slds-grid" >
        <div class="calendar" ontouchmove={handleScroll} onscroll={handleScroll}> </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

**meta**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="fullCalendarTest">
    <apiVersion>46.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__AppPage,lightning__RecordPage,lightning__HomePage,lightningCommunity__Default">
            <property name="objectName" label="Object name" type="String" required="true" default="Event"></property>
            <property name="startField" label="Start time field name" description="This needs to be a datetime field on the object that indicates the event start time" type="String" required="true" default="StartDateTime"></property>
            <property name="endField" label="End time field name" description="This needs to be a datetime field on the object that indicates the event end time" type="String" required="true" default="EndDateTime"></property>
            <property name="titleField" label="Event title field" type="String" required="true" default="Subject"></property>
            <property name="colorField" label="Color field" description="Any valid CSS value can go here" type="String" default=""></property>
            <property name="allDayField" label="All day event field" description="Field that specifies if the event is an all day event" type="String" default="IsAllDayEvent"></property>
            <property name="additionalFilter" label="Additional Filter" description="starts with AND or OR - end of SOQL statement" type="String" default=""></property>
            <property name="aspectRatio" label="Calendar Aspect Ratio" description="higher values makes the calendar shorter vertically" type="String" default="1.35"></property>
            <property name="height" label="Height of Calendar" description="height of calendar in pixels. unset = automatic" type="Integer" default="650"></property>
            <property name="weekView" label="Full Calendar week view type" type="String" datasource="timeGridWeek,dayGridWeek" default="timeGridWeek" />
            <property name="dayView" label="Full Calendar day view type" type="String" datasource="timeGridDay,dayGridDay" default="timeGridDay" />
            <property name="listView" label="Full Calendar list view type" type="String" datasource="listDay,listWeek,listMonth" default="listMonth" />
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

**Apex**

```
public with sharing class FullCalendarController {

    public FullCalendarController() {}

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Object> getEventsNearbyDynamic(Date startDate, Date endDate, String objectName, String titleField, String startField, String endField, String colorField, String allDayField, String additionalFilter)  {
        Datetime lastMonth = Datetime.newInstance(startDate.year(),startDate.month(),startDate.day());
        //lastMonth = lastMonth.addMonths(-1);
        String lastMonthStr = lastMonth.formatGmt('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'hh:mm:ss\'Z\'');
        Datetime nextMonth = Datetime.newInstance(endDate.year(),endDate.month(),endDate.day());
        //nextMonth = nextMonth.addMonths(2).addDays(-1);
        String nextMonthStr = nextMonth.formatGmt('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'hh:mm:ss\'Z\'');
        String soqlQuery = '';
        if (additionalFilter == null) {
            additionalFilter = '';
        }
        if ((colorField != null) && (colorField != '')) {
            colorField = ','+colorField;
        } else {
            colorField = '';
        }
        if ((allDayField != null) && (allDayField != '')) {
            allDayField = ','+allDayField;
        } else {
             allDayField = '';
        }
        soqlQuery += 'SELECT Id, '+titleField+', '+startField+', '+endField + /*colorField +*/ allDayField+' FROM ' + objectName;
   
        soqlQuery += ' WHERE (('+startField+' >= '+lastMonthStr+' AND '+startField+' <= '+nextMonthStr+')';
        soqlQuery += ' OR ('+endField+' >= '+lastMonthStr+' AND '+endField+' <= '+nextMonthStr+'))';
        soqlQuery += additionalFilter;
        System.debug('startDate = ' + startDate.format());
        System.debug('endDate = ' + endDate.format());
        System.debug('objectName = ' + objectName);
        System.debug('titleField = ' + titleField);
        System.debug('startField = ' + startField);
        System.debug('endField = ' + endField);
        System.debug('colorField = ' + colorField);
        System.debug(soqlQuery);

        List<Object> q = Database.query(soqlQuery);
        if (q == null) {
            q = new List<Object>();
        }
        System.debug('results = ' + q.size());
        return q;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that while the `dateClick` recognizes this correction...

```
this.calendar.addEvent
```

the select has "this" mapped to the calendar object so changing the call to this...

```
this.addEvent
```

resolves the issue.  Not sure why the two events treat this differently, but I am not a JS architect so it alludes me.